# Jupyter notebook does not connect to kernel ever

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda, jupyter-irkernel

Win 10 x64 Python 3.8 Anaconda

I created a conda virtual environment, activated the environment & installed ipykernel and Jupyter with `pip install jupyter ipykernel`

No issues, installed fine. Started a notebook by typing `jupyter notebook` at the command prompt.

Server page opens (Firefox), click on new Python 3 (ipykernel) & the new notebook opens but never connects to the kernel.

In the console I get the following (on repeat)...

```
     import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.
[W 21:52:45.493 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68:727c04bcf32b4ed7b38b8198f457fcb1
[W 21:53:07.534 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68:727c04bcf32b4ed7b38b8198f457fcb1
[W 21:53:24.493 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[I 21:53:24.509 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68:727c04bcf32b4ed7b38b8198f457fcb1
[I 21:53:24.509 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68:727c04bcf32b4ed7b38b8198f457fcb1
[W 21:53:29.050 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 10 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:53:34.083 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 20 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:53:39.119 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 30 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:53:44.161 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 40 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:53:49.246 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 50 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:53:54.345 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 60 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:53:59.363 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 70 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:54:04.383 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 80 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:54:09.402 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 90 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:54:14.502 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 100 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[W 21:54:19.520 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 110 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[I 21:54:24.295 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled1.ipynb
[W 21:54:24.679 NotebookApp] Nudge: attempt 120 on kernel c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68
[E 21:54:24.679 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68/channels?session_id=727c04bcf32b4ed7b38b8198f457fcb1 (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/c3d919e4-1d9d-482b-b3cc-d6bd8f1dde68/channels?session_id=727c04bcf32b4ed7b38b8198f457fcb1', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "d:\opencv\courses\beginers\opencv-env\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 956, in _accept_connection
        await open_result
      File "d:\opencv\courses\beginers\opencv-env\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 349, in __wakeup
        future.result()
    tornado.util.TimeoutError: Timeout
```

I check to see if `pywin32` is installed in the environment, yes its there alright.

So I've basically gone through all such questions on SO going back at least 4 years.

**Things that DO NOT WORK!!!**

Downgrading Tornado does not work.

Changing proxy server settings does not work.

Copying `pywin32` DLLs over to the appropiate Windows folder does not work.

Uninstalling & reinstalling Jupyter does not work.

Deleting the evironment & starting again does not work.

Running Jupyter notebook from the same directory as the environment does not work.

Any takers?

**EDIT**

Jupyter works fine in the base environment without `ipykernel`

What worked was `conda create -n myenv "python=3.8" jupyter`
It looks like the `pip` version doesnt like conda, see @foglerit's comments below.

Comment: If you are using Anaconda, why are you installing jupyter with `pip install`? Try to create a new conda environment and use conda to install jupyter, like: `conda create -n myenv "python=3.8" jupyter`

Comment: @foglerit I was following the set up instructions on a OpenCV course

Comment: conda and pip still don't play well together. Check this: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment I suggest you install everything using conda, or use virtualenv+pip.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VPN, close it and retry.
If you are use proxy, disable it and retry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).